# ADO VS DAO objects programmatic differences

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I looked at the differences between ADO and DAO online almost all the sources talk about which one to use and what advantage one has over the other. What I want to know is the programmatic differences.

ADO code  usually starts as

```
Dim cnStr As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cnRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
```

DAO starts as

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM orders", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Why is object instantiation using `New` keyword only needed in ADO connection. Isn't DAO object oriented as well?

Comment: It's just a difference in *where* objects are being constructed. In your first sample, you're creating a `Recordset` object yourself. In the second, the `OpenRecordset` method is performing that task.

Comment: You've been asking a lot of questions with an incorrect base assumption. This one implies a lack of knowledge of what the `New` keyword actually does. You don't need to use it at all to create ADODB recordsets, `Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset` and then `Set rs = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM orders")` works perfectly fine and is close to that DAO code functionally.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that it's a static class that's why you don't need to instantiate it every time.